# Merge folders on different drives in linux?

Tags: linux, files

I would like to merge the contents of two folders with the same same, from the linux terminal.

```
Drive 1\Folder

Drive 2\Folder
```

I want all files and sub-files in drive 1's folder to go to drive 2's folder, i tried to use MV and i got an error saying:

`unable to remove target: Is a directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp -r Drive\ 1/Folder/* Drive\ 2/Folder/`

I always prefer to `cp` rather than `mv` as it means I still have a copy of the original if in case something happens in the transfer.

After the copy is complete you can `rm -r Drive\ 1/Folder`.

This should also deal with the issue `mv` is having with moving the directory.

Hope that helps

Comment: Copying also sets the SELinux properties of the files being moved. The 'mv' command maintains the previous properties which can lead to confusing behavior in services and difficulties in accessing files otherwise completely correct permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Using `cp -ru drive1/* drive2` will copy everything in drive1 to drive2. The `-r` means to copy recursively. The `-u` means to update by copying only when the source file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing.